# RSA, cipher, Cryptosystem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

[image]

I genuinely have no idea how to go about solving this, any hints would be helpful

Comment: Is this the whole problem? Are we supposed to know who Eve is? I'm not sure how to solve this but I do notice that two different people have the same public key, and all the employees of company B are using the same modulus in their public keys. Maybe this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation

Comment: Here's my guess: Eve can decrypt $M$ by finding the private key $d$, which she can calculate if she has the totient of $9997$. The weakness might be that Company B has revealed that the totient is coprime to $17$, $19$, and $21$ (and therefore $3$ and $7$), and that might reduce the list of possible totients to a small enough number to make it possible to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: company B uses the same modulus with three different public exponents. That means that the attacker has access to:

$$C_1 \equiv M^{17} \pmod{9997}$$
$$C_2 \equiv M^{19} \pmod{9997}$$
$$C_3 \equiv M^{21} \pmod{9997}$$

More importantly, for any (possibly negative) integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ we have:

$$C_1^{k_1} \equiv \left ( M^{17} \right )^{k_1} \equiv M^{17k_1} \pmod{9997}$$

$$C_2^{k_2} \equiv \left ( M^{19} \right )^{k_2} \equiv M^{19k_2} \pmod{9997}$$

Multiply these two together (using basic modular arithmetic) to get:

$$C_1^{k_1} \cdot C_2^{k_2} \equiv M^{17k_1 + 19k_2} \pmod{9997}$$

Now, big hint: 17 and 19 are coprime. Can you finish? Note that negative $k_1$ and $k_2$ are perfectly allowed, because inverses are well-defined modulo $9997$ and can be computed efficiently using the extended Euclidean algorithm - the only case inverses don't exist is when $C_1$ or $C_2$ are not coprime to $9997$, in which case you have accidentally factored the public key anyway.

---

(this is of course ignoring the fact that these particular public keys are easily factored into the private key anyway, and that RSA is, thankfully, not used like that in the real world)

Comment: Oh, each of $C_n$ are ciphertexts of $M$ generated by the respective public key. That took me a few minutes to figure out. And I think we can assume Eve has been able to intercept all three ciphertexts and all three public key pairs from Company B.

Comment: Ohhh i fully understand everything you've done so far, could you possibly explain why we disregarded $C_3 \equiv M^{21} \pmod{9997}$

Comment: also would it possible to finish this off, i have ideas but im not 100% sure if i would be correct?

Comment: I think we want to choose $k_1$ and $k_2$ intelligently, possibly so that $17k_1+19k_2=1$?

Comment: thats what i thought and it gave me $k_1=9$ and $k_2=-8$, but where do we go from here?

Comment: I think calculate $C_1^{k_1}\cdot C_2^{k_2}(\mod9997)$. Which then I think equals $M$.

Comment: That's right (and we disregard $C_3$ because it's not needed, you only need two ciphertexts of the same plaintext encrypted with coprime public exponents to obtain a linear combination like Todd shows - 17, 19 and 21 are pairwise coprime so you could use $C_1$ and $C_2$, or $C_2$ and $C_3$, or even $C_1$ and $C_3$)